# Maven throws "java.lang.OutOfMemoryError"

Tags: java, maven-2, out-of-memory

I'm compiling an open source project with "mvn install" but ended up with `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space`. I tried to execute `java -Xmx256m` but the output was java synopsis which indicated it's an invalid command.

I'm using `jdk1.5.0_08`, any ideas why this is happening?

Thanks,

Comment: It's open question ;) The answer might be MAVEN_OPTS="-Xmx513m" etc. ;)

Answer (score 55, accepted):

Set the environment variable:

```
MAVEN_OPTS="-Xmx512m"
```

Comment: Sometimes is good also to extend perm memory size - MAVEN_OPTS="-Xmx512m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m"

Comment: Setting MAVEN_OPTS alone is not sufficient if the build fails while running unit tests. In such cases, you may have to configure the "argLine" of maven-surefire-plugin explicitly.

Comment: I was getting this error on mvn install, using "mvn install -DMAVEN_OPTS=-Xmx1024m" solved my problem!

Answer (score 19):

It depends on which JVM instance require more memory.
As example, if tests are forked (by default), and fails due OutOfMemoryError then try configure plugin which launching them:

```
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <argLine>-Xmx1024m</argLine>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

Comment: Can I add Xmx1024m -Xms1024m as well?

Comment: Yep, <argLine>-Xmx1g -Xms1g</argLine> should work

Answer (score 9):

Not only heap memory. You have to increase perm size also to resolve that exception in maven
use these variables in environment variable.

variable name: MAVEN_OPTS
variable value: -Xmx512m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m

Comment: How can you get the current value of `Xmx` and `MaxPermSize`? After all, I can't increase the values without knowing what they're already set to.

Comment: I'm not sure of MaxPermSize, but Xmx is usually 1/4th of the physical memory. Again, this may vary depending on the JRE implementations and/or "server", "client" mode of JVM.

Comment: -bash: export: `-XX:MaxPermSize=256m': not a valid identifier

Answer (score 6):

Sometimes, if you use other programs inside maven, like in integration tests or Surefire, the MAVEN_OPTS is not enough. Apart from MAVEN_OPTS, try to use JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS. This did the trick for me in Maven when running some integration tests:

```
export JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS="-Xmx2048m -XX:MaxPermSize=1024m -Xms2048m"
```

Reference:
[osx maven running tests Exception: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError thrown from the UncaughtExceptionHandler in thread "main"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24647558/osx-maven-running-tests-exception-java-lang-outofmemoryerror-thrown-from-the-un)

Answer (score 1):

on a Unix-like system:

```
export MAVEN_OPTS="-Xmx1024m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m"
```

[OutOfMemoryError](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/OutOfMemoryError)

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively use `set MAVEN_OPTS="-XX:MaxPermSize=256m"` while running from command prompt.

Answer (score 0):

I always use this with my shell on ubuntu:

```
export MAVEN_OPTS="-Xmx512m -XX:MaxPermSize=500m"
```

Answer (score -1):

Try to change or update your Maven install. I had this problem but I solved it by upgrading Maven (3.0.5 to 3.3.3).

Answer (score -5):

I experienced the same problem. According to [this link](http://www.mail-archive.com/users@maven.apache.org/msg66836.html) it might help to change jvm implementation - this can be done by setting JAVA_HOME system variable.

Try for example in the link mentioned ibm jvm or oracle jrockit:

```
SET JAVA_HOME=C:\bea10\jrockit160_22
mvn install
```