# Maven Cobertura OutOfMemoryError

Tags: maven-2, maven, out-of-memory, cobertura

I am using Maven site:run to generate a cobertura code coverage...

The following is my pom.xml configuration for cobertura:

```
<reporting>
    ...
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>cobertura-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3</version>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</reporting>
```

However I am getting OutOfMemoryError at the end of the site:run.  Please suggest how to get rid of this error. (I have tried all those -Xmx, -XX options...)

```
Exception in thread "Thread-0" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedSerializationConstructorAccessor74.newInstance(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
        at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.newInstance(ObjectStreamClass.java:924)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1737)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1329)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:351)
        at java.util.HashMap.readObject(HashMap.java:1030)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor347.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:974)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1849)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1753)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1329)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1947)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadObject(ObjectInputStream.java:480)
        at net.sourceforge.cobertura.coveragedata.CoverageDataContainer.readObject(CoverageDataContainer.java:373)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor348.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:974)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1849)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1753)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1329)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:351)
        at java.util.HashMap.readObject(HashMap.java:1030)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor347.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:974)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1849)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1753)
```

Comment: Dupe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1920059/maven-throws-java-lang-outofmemoryerror

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use this property in your pom.xml :

```
<project>
...
<build>
...
</build>

<properties>
    <cobertura.maxmem>256M</cobertura.maxmem>
</properties>

</project>
```

Comment: I got it! Adding <cobertura.maxmem>512m</cobertura.maxmem> in pom.xml resolved my issue. Thanks everyone

Comment: Then consider up-voting and accepting the answer from Jean-Philippe Briend.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try something like `export MAVEN_OPTS=-Xmx1024m` (Or the highest value that match your machine)?

If you still don't have enough memory to run maven, then I would suggest you try to disable other  plugin and exclude some classes from the test coverage to check if it's really a memory issue.

```
<plugin>
 <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
 <artifactId>cobertura-maven-plugin</artifactId>
 <configuration>
  <instrumentation>
    <ignores>
      <ignore>com.example.boringcode.*</ignore>
    </ignores>
    <excludes>
      <exclude>com/example/dullcode/**/*.class</exclude>
      <exclude>com/example/**/*Test.class</exclude>
    </excludes>
  </instrumentation>
</configuration>
```

http://mojo.codehaus.org/cobertura-maven-plugin/usage.html

**EDIT**

Other ideas:

Set the following properties (see the [cobertura plugin properties](http://maven-plugins.sourceforge.net/maven-cobertura-plugin/properties.html))

```
-Dmaven.cobertura.report.maxmemory=xxx
-Dmaven.cobertura.instrumentation.maxmemory=xxx
```

Try to use fork or increase the memory with the following. I'm not sure whether it works for cobertura, but seem to work for junit. Snippet from this [page](http://www.coderanch.com/t/108947/Ant-Maven-Other-Build-Tools/maven-junit-out-memory-error):

```
<plugin>
...
<configuration>
<forkMode>pertest</forkMode>
</configuration>
</plugin>
```

or

```
<plugin>
...
<configuration>
...
<argLine>-Xmx512m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m</argLine> 
</configuration>
</plugin>
```

Comment: This is my MAVEN_OPTS: -XX:MaxPermSize=512m -Xms128m -Xmx600m   (I changed it to -Xmx1024m but I got the following error:

Error occurred during initialization of VM
Could not reserve enough space for object heap
Could not create the Java virtual machine.)

Comment: Hi ewernli,

I tried but still issue exists... this is the change I did it in pom.xml: (I excluded the biggest packages)

            <instrumentation>
              <excludes>
                <exclude>com/xxx/**/*Test.class</exclude>
                <exclude>com/xxx/yyy/rating/**/*.class</exclude>
                <exclude>com/xxx/yyy/common/**/*.class</exclude>
              </excludes>
            </instrumentation>

Comment: I got it! Adding <cobertura.maxmem>512m</cobertura.maxmem> in pom.xml resolved my issue. Thanks everyone!