# out of mempry for large number of tests. using maven and sonar

Tags: maven, out-of-memory, sonarqube

i am using sonar 2.6
and on running the command:

```
mvn site cobertura:cobertura
```

i am getting the following error...

```
Tests run: 1397, Failures: 10, Errors: 117, Skipped: 0

Flushing results...
Flushing results done
Exception in thread "Thread-0" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:974
)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1849)

    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1
753)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1329)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:351)
    at java.util.ArrayList.readObject(ArrayList.java:593)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor33.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAcces
sorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:974
)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1849)

    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1
753)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1329)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:19
47)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadObject(ObjectInputStream.java:48
0)
    at net.sourceforge.cobertura.coveragedata.LineData.readObject(LineData.j
ava:525)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor32.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAcces
sorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:974
)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1849)

    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1
753)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1329)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:351)
    at java.util.HashMap.readObject(HashMap.java:1030)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor35.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAcces
sorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:974
)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1849)

    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1
753)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1329)
[ERROR] There are test failures.
```

My machine has win-XP with 32 bit environment and 3.2gb RAM.
PS i have already set the env variaable MAVEN_OPTS to 512M.
 As i am not able to set it to any higher value coz then i get

```
Unable to load JVM error.
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2048667/maven-cobertura-outofmemoryerror

Comment: To which values are you setting MAVEN_OPTS? It should be no problem so set it to 1024M.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few properties to look at.  In addition to cobertura.maxmen (per [Raghuram's pointer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2048667/maven-cobertura-outofmemoryerror) above, look at the configuration for the [surefire plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-surefire-plugin/test-mojo.html).  Make sure that `forkMode` is not `never` - but experiment.

Note in the description of the `jvm` property that "JVM settings are not inherited from MAVEN_OPTS."  Try setting your memory options there, instead.