# Maven Throws "java.lang.OutOfMemoryError" when generating Sure-fire reports

Tags: java, multithreading, maven-surefire-plugin

I know this question appeared all along long time,
but none of the solution worked successful to me

[Maven throws "java.lang.OutOfMemoryError"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1920059/maven-throws-java-lang-outofmemoryerror/1927072)

[How to deal with "java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space" error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37335/how-to-deal-with-java-lang-outofmemoryerror-java-heap-space-error)

though I tried above two solutions, and also tried other options suggested by 
other answers still I was ended up in the below error

```
17-Dec-2018 11:36:54    Exception in thread "ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-5" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: unable to create new native thread
17-Dec-2018 11:36:54            at java.lang.Thread.start0(Native Method)
17-Dec-2018 11:36:54            at java.lang.Thread.start(Thread.java:717)
17-Dec-2018 11:36:54            at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.createWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1486)
17-Dec-2018 11:36:54            at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.tryAddWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1517)
17-Dec-2018 11:36:54            at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.deregisterWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1609)
17-Dec-2018 11:36:54            at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:167)
17-Dec-2018 11:36:54    Exception in thread "ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-0" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: unable to create new native thread
17-Dec-2018 11:36:54            at java.lang.Thread.start0(Native Method)
17-Dec-2018 11:36:54            at java.lang.Thread.start(Thread.java:717)
17-Dec-2018 11:36:54            at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.createWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1486)
17-Dec-2018 11:36:54            at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.tryAddWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1517)
17-Dec-2018 11:36:54            at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.deregisterWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1609)
17-Dec-2018 11:36:54            at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:167)
```

to make it clear,

I have used sure-fire to run the testng tests and generate the report accordingly... so I first applied the approach to add the argline, it doesn't help. then I tried adding MAVEN_OPTS and increased values ranging from 256 to 1024 that doesn't works either finally added JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS, still it doesn't works even though i tried multiple values to specify

Are there any other choices left to try out to resolve the problem

Don't mark this duplicate... I need a better solution than already existing.

**Edited**

Hardware Details using command `lscpu`

```
Architecture:          x86_64
CPU op-mode(s):        32-bit, 64-bit
Byte Order:            Little Endian
CPU(s):                8
On-line CPU(s) list:   0-7
Thread(s) per core:    1
Core(s) per socket:    4
Socket(s):             2
NUMA node(s):          1
Vendor ID:             GenuineIntel
CPU family:            6
Model:                 61
Model name:            Intel Core Processor (Broadwell)
Stepping:              2
CPU MHz:               2197.454
BogoMIPS:              4394.90
Hypervisor vendor:     KVM
Virtualization type:   full
L1d cache:             32K
L1i cache:             32K
L2 cache:              4096K
NUMA node0 CPU(s):     0-7
```

OS Details using `uname -a`

```
Linux pt-00-00 3.10.0-327.4.5.el7.x86_64 #1 SMP Thu Jan 21 04:10:29 EST 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Details for `cat /proc/meminfo`

```
MemTotal:       24517356 kB
MemFree:        24048256 kB
MemAvailable:   24054212 kB
Buffers:           35556 kB
Cached:           142932 kB
SwapCached:            0 kB
Active:            81092 kB
Inactive:         144820 kB
Active(anon):      47652 kB
Inactive(anon):    24724 kB
Active(file):      33440 kB
Inactive(file):   120096 kB
Unevictable:           0 kB
Mlocked:               0 kB
SwapTotal:       4193276 kB
SwapFree:        4193276 kB
Dirty:                 8 kB
Writeback:             0 kB
AnonPages:         47688 kB
Mapped:            40864 kB
Shmem:             24896 kB
Slab:              55872 kB
SReclaimable:      27304 kB
SUnreclaim:        28568 kB
KernelStack:        5520 kB
PageTables:         4180 kB
NFS_Unstable:          0 kB
Bounce:                0 kB
WritebackTmp:          0 kB
CommitLimit:    16451952 kB
Committed_AS:     238360 kB
VmallocTotal:   34359738367 kB
VmallocUsed:      169716 kB
VmallocChunk:   34359564288 kB
HardwareCorrupted:     0 kB
AnonHugePages:     12288 kB
HugePages_Total:       0
HugePages_Free:        0
HugePages_Rsvd:        0
HugePages_Surp:        0
Hugepagesize:       2048 kB
DirectMap4k:       63344 kB
DirectMap2M:    25102336 kB
```

Details for `vmstat -s`

```
 24517356 K total memory
   234276 K used memory
    81704 K active memory
   145092 K inactive memory
 24048760 K free memory
    35656 K buffer memory
   198664 K swap cache
  4193276 K total swap
        0 K used swap
  4193276 K free swap
     3630 non-nice user cpu ticks
       24 nice user cpu ticks
     6329 system cpu ticks
 21548595 idle cpu ticks
     1549 IO-wait cpu ticks
        0 IRQ cpu ticks
       16 softirq cpu ticks
       25 stolen cpu ticks
   142239 pages paged in
   101165 pages paged out
        0 pages swapped in
        0 pages swapped out
  1169647 interrupts
  1713506 CPU context switches
   1546461109 boot time
        50951 forks
```

Comment: I suppose surefire configured to run in separate JVM.

Comment: i didnt get it clear

Comment: surefire plugin start separate process, it have its own java options. See Eugen Covaci answer to change them.

Comment: I did that, btw it was already listed solution... still it doesn't works

Comment: Try to increase memory limit even more. Also check that you can run test in your IDE. Maybe it is actual problem with them.

Comment: I check error message again. It says that it can't create new thread. You may want to limit amount of created thread. As temporary solution you can try to reduce stack size by `-Xss256k` (may lead to stack overflow exception).

Comment: i was able to try it in my ide as well as my local windows system. this problem occurs when i tries to run in linux server....

Comment: i will check the stack solution...

Comment: Your linux may be configured with some limit on number native thread per process. Execute `ulimit –u` on your linux machine to get the limit.

Comment: it returns `4096`

Comment: Looks good. So you have to find out why so many thread created. I can't help you with that, you need to inspect you code.

Comment: Please post the relevant hardware/software for that linux server. (Cpu, memory,linux distro,kernel params) etc

Comment: @EugenCovaci check whether the details are enough

Comment: Not enough. Run the following commands: `cat /proc/meminfo` and `vmstat -s`

Comment: I have updated the memory details @user10638668

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can configure the `maven-surefire-plugin` like this:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>x.x.x</version>
    <configuration>
        <argLine>-Xmx2048m -XX:MaxPermSize=1024m</argLine>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
```

to set JVM arguments.

Comment: `ignoring option MaxPermSize=1024m; support was removed in 8.0` and got the following error

Comment: @AmuD7 Remove `-XX:MaxPermSize=1024m` part it is not supported in your version of JVM (it is removed in 8.0).

Comment: yeah I tried both choice with and without `-XX:MaxPermSize=1024m` still it end up in the same errors

Comment: Note that the exception shown is not necessarily a heapspace-issue (although it might be because of a heap that is *too large*) but rather a shortage of OS-resources.